# Secure UI but publicly allow AJAX request

Tags: symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

I am working on a project using the API Platform.

I would like to have the documentation of the UI secured with basic authentication, while some of the routes should be publicly available.

For example:

```
/**
 * An ordered dish.
 *
 * @ApiResource(
 *     attributes={"access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_USER')"},
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get"={"access_control"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')"},
 *         "post"={"access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"}
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get"={"access_control"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')"}
 *     }
 * )
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="uitgekookt_dish")
 */
class Dish
```

When I view the docs in the browser, i can simply access /api/dishes, because of the IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY. I see other get/post methods available there as well (though some of the post methods are secured).

However, the docs should not be available at all publicly. How do I ensure, in Symfony 4, that I seperate my security config for docs and ajax requests?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get it right but you want to restrict `/api/doc` (or whatever url you are using for docs) so add it to `access_control` in security.yaml

```
security:
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/doc, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN] }
```

Comment: the docs in API-platform are available through /api. There is no /doc

Answer (score 0):

First, disable Swagger UI that is loaded for every page, and register it as a known location as pointed out in [this docs entry](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/swagger/#changing-the-swagger-ui-location):

```
# app/config/routes.yaml
api_platform:
    # ...
    enable_swagger_ui: false

# app/config/routes.yaml
swagger_ui:
    path: /api/docs
    controller: api_platform.swagger.action.ui
```

Then, as pointed out by @zajca, add an access control route to secure this page, and the underlying JSON and Hydra endpoints:

```
 security:
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/docs, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN] }
```